# Printing a structure in C

Tags: c, file, io, printf, fwrite

I am making some changes in wireshark source code. At one particular point, I print out a structure called `SSLDecoder` like this

```
FILE *f;  
f=fopen("file.txt","a+");
size_decoder=sizeof(SslDecoder);  
for(i=0; i < size_decoder; i++){
    fprintf(f,"%02x",*(ssl_session->client_new+i));
}
fprintf(f,"\n");
```

`ssl_session` is of type `struct SslDecryptSession` which is defined as

```
typedef struct _SslDecryptSession {
    guchar _master_secret[SSL_MASTER_SECRET_LENGTH];
    guchar _session_id[256];
    guchar _client_random[32];
    guchar _server_random[32];
    StringInfo session_id;
    StringInfo session_ticket;
    StringInfo server_random;
    StringInfo client_random;
    StringInfo master_secret;
    StringInfo handshake_data;
    /* the data store for this StringInfo must be allocated explicitly with a capture lifetime scope */
    StringInfo pre_master_secret;
    guchar _server_data_for_iv[24];
    StringInfo server_data_for_iv;
    guchar _client_data_for_iv[24];
    StringInfo client_data_for_iv;

    gint state;
    SslCipherSuite cipher_suite;
    SslDecoder *server;
    SslDecoder *client;
    SslDecoder *server_new;
    SslDecoder *client_new;
    gcry_sexp_t private_key;
    StringInfo psk;
    guint16 version_netorder;
    StringInfo app_data_segment;
    SslSession session;
} SslDecryptSession;
```

`SslDecoder` is of type

```
typedef struct _SslDecoder {
    SslCipherSuite* cipher_suite;
    gint compression;
    guchar _mac_key_or_write_iv[48];
    StringInfo mac_key; /* for block and stream ciphers */
    StringInfo write_iv; /* for AEAD ciphers (at least GCM, CCM) */
    SSL_CIPHER_CTX evp;
    SslDecompress *decomp;
    guint32 seq;
    guint16 epoch;
    SslFlow *flow;
} SslDecoder;
```

However, the output printed to the file is irregular.
Sample output is here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/avdVXPyM)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

I later use this output in the file to populate another decoder like this (Right now as it is, I face a seg fault because of the irregular print to the file)

```
SslDecoder *temp_decoder;
c = malloc(sizeof(SslDecoder));

for (i=0; i<sizeof(SslDecoder); i++){
    fscanf(f,"%02x",&c[i]);
}
memcpy(temp_decoder,c, sizeof(SslDecoder));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform pointer arithmetic, the pointer is offset by a multiple of the size of the type pointed to; it does *not* offset the pointer by the specified number of *bytes*.  Remember, if you have `T* p`, then `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`.

In your code, you do:

```
size_decoder=sizeof(SslDecoder);  
for(i=0; i < size_decoder; i++){
    fprintf(f,"%02x",*(ssl_session->client_new+i));
}
```

`*(ssl_session->client_new+i)` offsets the `client_new` pointer by `i * sizeof (SslDecoder)` bytes on each iteration.

You instead intend to advance the pointer by only a single byte on each iteration, so you instead must perform pointer arithmetic on a pointer to `char`:

```
size_decoder=sizeof(SslDecoder);  
const unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*) ssl_session->client_new;
for(i=0; i < size_decoder; i++){
    fprintf(f,"%02x", p[i]);
}
```

And you similarly will need to do something similar when reading the file back.  I should also point out that in your reading code:

```
SslDecoder *temp_decoder;
c = malloc(sizeof(SslDecoder));

for (i=0; i<sizeof(SslDecoder); i++){
    fscanf(f,"%02x",&c[i]);
}
memcpy(temp_decoder,c, sizeof(SslDecoder));
```

that the `memcpy` call is incorrect; you have not allocated any memory for `temp_decoder`.  You shouldn't need to use `memcpy` at all:

```
SslDecoder *temp_decoder = malloc(sizeof *temp_decoder);
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*) temp_decoder;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(SslDecoder); i++){
    int temp; // "%x" corresponds to an int type
    fscanf(f, "%02x", &temp);
    p[i] = (unsigned char) temp;
}
```

Comment: For the writing section, I do need to do a memcpy call after this code right.
`memcpy(temp_decoder, p,sizeof (temp_decoder));`

Comment: @AbhimanyuKhanna No, you do not need the `memcpy` call in the example I showed; `p` points to the same address as `temp_decoder` (they just have different types for pointer arithmetic)., so it writes directly to the memory allocated for `temp_decoder`.